# backbone view el not appending

Tags: backbone.js, coffeescript

I have the following Backbone (in coffeescript) view where i pass an array and try to append each item to the el. However, I keep coming up with an empty el.

```
ItemTagList = Backbone.View.extend
  className  : "itemTagsContainer"
  initialize : (tags) ->
    this.render(tags.taglist)

  render: (taglist) ->
    taglist.forEach (tag) ->
      tag_span = _.template($("#tag").html(), {tag : tag} )
      $(this.el).append(tag_span)
      console.log(tag)
```

The template `$("#tag")` looks like this:

```
<a class='tag' href="/items?tagged_with=<%= tag =>"><%= tag =></a>
```

Upon rendering, the above will correctly iterate over the `taglist`, so I know that the taglist is properly passed to the Backbone View, as well as to the `render` function.

But if I do the following

```
itemTagList = new ItemTagList
  taglist : ["Tag1", "Tag2"]

console.log(itemTagList.el)
```

I always get the empty `el`, i.e.

```
 <div class="itemTagsContainer"></div>
```

instead of

```
 <div class="itemTagsContainer">
   <a class='tag' href="/items?tagged_with=Tag1">Tag1</a>
   <a class='tag' href="/items?tagged_with=Tag2">Tag2</a>
 </div>
```

which is what I was hoping to get.

Can anyone help?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You just have a context problem inside your [`forEach`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/forEach) callback function; the `@` (AKA `this`) will be the global object (`window` in a browser) so `this.el` isn't what you think it is. You can get around this by using a [fat-arrow (`=>`)](http://coffeescript.org/#fat_arrow) when defining your callback function:

```
render: (taglist) ->
  taglist.forEach (tag) =>
    tag_span = _.template($("#tag").html(), tag: tag)
    @$el.append(tag_span)
    console.log(tag)
```

I've also switched to [`@$el`](http://backbonejs.org/#View-%24el) since your view will already have a cached version of `$(@el)`.

The context in a `forEach` callback depends on what mode you're in:

> If a `thisArg` parameter is provided to `forEach`, it will be used as the this value for each callback invocation as if `callback.call(thisArg, element, index, array)` was called. If `thisArg` is `undefined` or `null`, the `this` value within the function depends on whether the function is in strict mode or not (passed value if in strict mode, global object if in non-strict mode).

I'd recommend using `=>` so that you don't have to worry about it; alternatively, you could use the `thisArg`:

```
taglist.forEach (tag) -> ...., @
```

but that tends to be a bit ugly and cumbersome in CoffeeScript.

Comment: Wow! I just worked! I was up all night trying to figure out the problem. Thanks for pointing out the solution. I really need to wrap my head around more on coffeescript and javascript.

Comment: @DannyClay: You're welcome. Getting the right value of `@` (AKA `this`) is probably the most common (Coffee|Java)Script problem. You'll often see `var _this = this;`, `var that = this;`, or `var self = this;` in JavaScript, then you can use `_this`, `that`, or `self` in place of `this`.